# Unable to select a field generated by link_to_add_fields with capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, simple-form, rspec-rails

I have the following element in my view  template: `<%= link_to_add_fields "Add event", f, :events %>`

This opens up a set of fields, which themselves are generated by `simple_fields_for`. These fields correctly display in the browser running off my local server, so that is not the problem.

However, I can't figure out how to get capybara to `fill_in` those fields. capybara does not raise an error in clicking the `Add event` button from `link_to_add_fields`, but raises the error when I try to fill in the form, saying that it is `Unable to find field`. Any guesses?

Comment: Are you using a JS capable driver? Show the code that you're trying to use to fill_in, the html that you think that code should fill, and the exact error you get - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Sorry, I should just close this question. This is also probably solved by setting `:js => true `. However, I cannot verify that this is the problem, because now having set  `:js => true ` I'm getting the following error message: 

`Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError: Unable to load URL: http://cms.eta.dev:5000/auth/identity because of error loading http://cms.eta.dev:5000/auth/identity: Unknown error`

This is despite implementing DatabaseCleaner. I will have to work on that problem first before determing if this is still a problem.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole to confirm though: I am using capybara WebKit

Comment: You would only be using capybara-webkit when js: true is set - without that you would be using rack-test which doesn't run JS at all so the JS run by `link_to_add_fields` would never happen and the fields wouldn't exist to fill in.  So, yes it will probably be fixed once you get a JS capable driver working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use id inside your `link_to_add_fields` and access that id in your capybara `fill_in`.

`<%= link_to_add_fields "Add event", f, :events, :id => 'something' %>`

and use id

`fill_in "something", with: 'example'`

Comment: I haven't been able to try out this solution (or any solution) yet because of other problems that make is that the test isn't even getting to that point anymore. But keep in mind that this `link_to_add_fields ` creates a unique ID number for every set of fields that it creates. In other words, each time you press the link, it creates a new ID. I would have to figure out a way to incorporate that unique ID in the `fill-in ` command.